# Using SSH/Powershell to run windows programs on a Win10 machine with WSL?

Tags: bash, ssh, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## TLDR

I want to run commands such as "powershell.exe" or "notepad.exe" from my notebook's SSH client, which is connected to my workstation's WSL2 SSHD server

## Situation:

- I have a laptop with an SSH client (using Powershell), currently connected to another local workstation using keys. The connection is successful, both from Powershell and VSCode-SSH
- The host PC is running SSHD inside WSL2 running Ubuntu 18.04, which is where my development environment lives
- If I go into bash (or any Ubuntu terminal) in my workstation PC, I can run certain Windows programs such as `powershell.exe` or `notepad.exe`, which is really handy to automate workflows
- When calling `powershell.exe` from the host PC, I can open the process from bash (really handy!)
- When trying to do this from my local Powershell client, I get:

```
user@WORKSTATION:~$ powershell.exe
powershell.exe: command not found
```

Any experts out there know **why does powershell.exe fail via SSH, but not locally?**

Thank you!

Comment: Have you at least checked your PATH?  You will notice that when it works.. it contains ":/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32".. what about when it DOESN'T WORK?

Comment: Option a: PATH. Use "where powershell.exe" to get the full local path and use it  fromt he remote. If it works, it is a path issue (i.e):
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Option b: https://superuser.com/questions/1273682/execute-command-script-in-windows-10-remotely-from-linux-machine

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas , it seems the $PATH is slightly different, do you know why is the $PATH I call from SSH different than the local machine's?

Comment: @DGoiko , the command "where powershell.exe" also doesn't work, is this also a $PATH issue?

Comment: @SebastianRivas Did you use "where powershell.exe" from your local machine or from ssh? I meant you should execute it LOCALLY, then copy the full path it will give you and use that full path REMOTELLY instead of the powershell.exe short-name. If where is not working locally I've no idea why, maybe they removed it in new windows versions and I'm just a dinosaur!

Comment: It is different for security reasons I am sure.  Log in through SSH.  type `export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32`  Try the command then.. see if it works.

Comment: Btw the command is `whereis` or `which` not `where`. This is why it is not working for @SebastianRivas

Answer (score 0):

The problem as stated in the comments is that when you execute WSL locally, Windows injects it's PATH into Linux one. If you connect through SSH this process won't happen.

You can manually add the Windows Path to the file /etc/environment it will be read from SSH.

Hope it helps